# Thumbdrive fix? "unable to detect file system" 16GB causes 2GB partition

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, fdisk

I have a Corsair Flash Voyager 16GB drive. It has worked fine for ages, though I barely use it. I wanted to wipe all the data on it/return it to zeros, so I used

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1
```

But it said 2GB was copied, and that didn't seem right. I went into gparted and created a new partition table (mdos) and then made a fat32 partition for the full usable 14gb. Gparted completed the operation, then said it couldn't find a filesystem. Plugging it in made a 16gb "drive" show up in nautilus, but right-click didn't give any properties info. Left-click caused a 2GB ejectable drive link to spawn in nautilus.

Obviously, I went all "wtf?" and went to ubuntu irc for answers. I was guided through using fdisk, but afterward the same problem appeared.

Here's the result of fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16039018496 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15296 cylinders, total 31326208 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdeb7c4d0
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    31326207    15662080   83  Linux
```

When I plug the drive in and click on 16GB a few times, here's what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEIPo.jpg

When I try to "eject" the 2Gb, I get a password popup that says "Authentication is required to unmount /dev/loop0 mounted by another user". I've never seen loop0 on anything in Ubuntu before.

Edit: If I right-click the 16GB and hit "Format" nothing happens. Here's what happens when I try to use GParted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6NJ5.jpg

How can I get the drive back to a single 14ish GB partition?

Edit 2: After plugging in the drive again, 
`sudo umount /dev/sdb` returns `"not mounted"` but `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` unmounts something. That's weird, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what happened, but here's what resolved the issue:

A) I thought I'd plug in my other 16GB Flash Voyager to compare fdisk results, in case it gave me a clue. Plugging it in popped up the same 16GB/2GB issue, with the same .txt test file I added to it. This, of course, made no sense. So, I rebooted the computer.

B) Following reboot, the 2nd 16GB drive (never used dd on it, full of files) showed up like normal.

C) Swapping it out with the 1st 16GB drive, I opened up GParted. In GParted I right-clicked the "Unknown" "Can't find filesystem" 14GB partition I'd created, and chose "Format" from the context menu. Formatting as FAT32 succeeded.

D) Unplug drive, re-plug it in, open GParted again. Delete partition, add new partition & name it. Operation successful.

Again, I have no idea what the hell happened, but it works fine now!